# How to get Video Picture from devices, which are as Image Processing Device installed?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm using AForge dll to connect my webcam into my code. When the Camera is installed just as a camera (In device manager), i get live video normally. Now a new driver has been released making this camera as Photo Processing device. On that way i don't get any picture. I have tried some other dlls too but they were not helping. 
The standard Camera Program from windows 10 can start the camera normally. 
Does anyone can help with this issue?

i have used for example the code in this example while in my tests 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osAOpsRYqVs

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports AForge.Video
Imports AForge.Video.DirectShow
Imports AForge

Public Class Form1
   Private WithEvents Cloc_Videosource As VideoCaptureDevice = Nothing

   'Gets the camera list 
   Private Sub B_GetCameras_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_GetCameras.Click
      Try
         Dim Loc_Devices As New FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice)
         CB_CAM.Items.Clear()
         If Loc_Devices.Count > 0 Then
            For Each Loc_FI As FilterInfo In Loc_Devices
               CB_CAM.Items.Add(Loc_FI.MonikerString)
            Next
         End If
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
      End Try
   End Sub

   Private Sub B_Stream_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_Stream.Click
      Try
         If Cloc_Videosource IsNot Nothing Then
            Cloc_Videosource.Stop()
            Cloc_Videosource = Nothing
         End If
         If CB_CAM.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Cloc_Videosource = New VideoCaptureDevice(CB_CAM.SelectedItem)

            If Cloc_Videosource.VideoCapabilities IsNot Nothing AndAlso Cloc_Videosource.VideoCapabilities.Count > 0 Then
               Cloc_Videosource.VideoResolution = Cloc_Videosource.VideoCapabilities(0)
            Else
               MsgBox("No video resolution found")
            End If
            Cloc_Videosource.ProvideSnapshots = True
            Cloc_Videosource.Start()
         End If
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
      End Try
   End Sub

   Private Sub B_GetPhoto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_GetPhoto.Click
      Try
         If Cloc_Videosource IsNot Nothing Then
            Cloc_Videosource.SimulateTrigger()
         End If
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
      End Try
   End Sub
   Private Sub Cloc_Videosource_NewFrame(sender As Object, eventArgs As NewFrameEventArgs) Handles Cloc_Videosource.NewFrame
      Try
         Dim Loc_Bitmap As New Drawing.Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame)
         'MsgBox("New Frame")
         'If PB_Live.Image IsNot Nothing Then PB_Live.Image.Dispose()
         PB_Live.Image = Loc_Bitmap
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
      End Try
   End Sub

   Private Sub Cloc_Videosource_SnapshotFrame(sender As Object, eventArgs As NewFrameEventArgs) Handles Cloc_Videosource.SnapshotFrame
      Try
         Dim Loc_Bitmap As New Drawing.Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame)
         If PB_Snapshot.Image IsNot Nothing Then PB_Snapshot.Image.Dispose()
         PB_Snapshot.Image = Loc_Bitmap
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
      End Try
   End Sub

   Private Sub Cloc_Videosource_Error(sender As Object, eventArgs As VideoSourceErrorEventArgs) Handles Cloc_Videosource.VideoSourceError
      Try
         MsgBox(eventArgs.Description.ToString)
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
      End Try
   End Sub

End Class
```